# Parameterless OnClick method call with DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a custom `Presenter` class and I cannot seem to get around having to pass an `android.view.View` object as a parameter into a method I want executed when user clicks on a button, even though I do not need the `View` object. Using `DataBinding`, is it possible to bind an `onClick` event to a method without parameters from `XML`?

```
<layout>
   <data>
     <variable
            name="presenter"
            type="com.somepackage.Presenter"/>
    </data>
    ...
    android:onClick="@{ presenter.onClick }"
    ...
</layout>
```

In the `Presenter` class, I must have the following signature, or code doesn't compile:

```
...
public void onClick( @NonNull View ignored ) {
     //do something that doesn't use the view parameter
}
...
```

What I would like to do is to have a method signature in my `Presenter` calss that doesn't have a View as a parameter:

```
...
public void onClick() {
     //do something that doesn't use the view parameter
}
...
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your xml you have to do
`android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onClick() }"` to call your method